# How to use "i" from loop? after loop is already stop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a projectile calculator, so it really need to change the way to calculate again & again until it is done.

```
<script>
function useif()
{
    var Height = Number(document.getElementById("Height").value);
    var Velocity = Number(document.getElementById("Velocity").value);
    var Range = Number(document.getElementById("Range").value);
    var First = ( ( ((Math.SQRT2 * Velocity) + (Math.sqrt(19.6) * Velocity * Height)) * Math.cos(0.785398163) ) / 9.8);

    document.getElementById("First").innerHTML = First;

    if (First < Range) 
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Need more velocity to success on this range";
    else
    {
        for (var i = -1.570796327; i < MaxValue; i+0.000000001;)
        {
            ( (( (Velocity * Math.sin(i)) + Math.sqrt(Velocity * Math.sin(i) * Velocity * Math.sin(i) - 19.6 * Height) )) / 9.8) * Velocity * Math.cos(i));
            if (result >= Range) break;
            document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = i;
            var degree = i * 57.295779513;
            document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = degree + "degree";
        }
    }

}
```

This is all of the function

```
<p>Height<br /><input id="Height" type="text" /><br></P>

<p>Range<br /><input id="Range" type="text" /><br></P>

<p>Velocity<br /><input id="Velocity" type="text" /><br></P>

<input type="button" value="Calculate!" onclick="useif()" />
<span id="show"></p>
```

I'm trying to show "degree" but I don't know why it didn't work

it seems that the problem is comming from the looping part that I'm really new to it and need lots of explanation

This is my JSfiddle just registered it
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=1m70MQhEGo

Comment: Why not alter your first question!?

Comment: You dont have an element with Id i in your html!

Comment: It might be good to create a JSFiddle which will let us debug with you. Also, what is your goal? Is it to show the `degree` value in the inner HTML?

Comment: Is MaxValue in the for loop defined?

Comment: What do you want to do by this line ?
`((((Velocity * Math.sin(i)) + Math.sqrt(Velocity * Math.sin(i) * Velocity * Math.sin(i) - 19.6 * Height))) / 9.8) * Velocity * Math.cos(i));`
other thing; in the for loop you should do `i += 0.000000001` instead of doing `i + 0.000000001;`

Comment: that's a distance calculate sector. Then it'll be check with range that have already been inserted

yes,the goal is to show the degree value

Comment: just added my jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few useless assignments going on all over the place confusing your program and a few variables were missing. After using the "JSHint" button a few times on fiddle I came to this working conclusion. Hope this helps you out bud.

Try this:

HTML:

```
    <p>Height
    <br />
    <input id="Height" type="text" />
    <br>
    </P>
    <p>Range
        <br />
        <input id="Range" type="text" />
        <br>
    </P>
    <p>Velocity
        <br />
        <input id="Velocity" type="text" />
        <br>
    </P>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate!" onclick="useif()" /> <span id="show">Output here</span>

    </p>
```

JS:

```
    window.useif = function () {
    var i;
    var MaxValue = 3;
    var Height = Number(document.getElementById("Height").value);
    var Velocity = Number(document.getElementById("Velocity").value);
    var Range = Number(document.getElementById("Range").value);
    var First = ((((Math.SQRT2 * Velocity) + (Math.sqrt(19.6) * Velocity * Height)) * Math.cos(0.785398163)) / 9.8);
    if (First < Range) document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Need more velocity to success on this range";
    else {
        for (i = -1.570796327; i < MaxValue; i += 0.0001) {
            result = ((((Velocity * Math.sin(i)) + Math.sqrt(Velocity * Math.sin(i) * Velocity * Math.sin(i) - 19.6 * Height))) / 9.8) * Velocity * Math.cos(i);
            if (result >= Range) break;

            var degree = i * 57.295779513;
            document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = degree + "degree";
        }
    }

};
```